# How to expand specific bootstrap accordion panel on hyperlink Click on another page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accordion

I have bootstrap accordion in my website and now I am trying to expand respective panels on 
hyperlink click (from another webpage of same website). I have already tried most of the solution provided on other .net communities as well but no luck. As I am new to JavaScript or jquery I might be coding something wrong. any advice to solve this would be really helpful.

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
   <div class="panel panel-success">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#accordionTwo">
                    <b>Vehicle Code Matching</b>
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="accordionTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
              Test paragraph 1
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-success">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#accordionThree">
                    <b>Vehicle Data Association</b>
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="accordionThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
              Test paragraph 2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-success">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#accordionFive">
                    <b>Data Cleansing</b>
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="accordionFive" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
               Test paragraph 3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the line  _I am trying to expand respective panels on hyperlink click (from anothe webpage of same website)_. If am not wrong and according to what I understood from your above lines **you want to expand panel which is in page 1 by clicking on a link which is in page 2?**

Comment: So at present which page will be visible here?? **page2**??

Comment: I have a list of product titles on index.aspx so I am trying to open/expand specific panel on product.aspx

Comment: It will be Page2 which has accordion

Comment: I am afraid that you cannot achieve this because for `jquery` to access the elements it has to be present in `DOM` and if you are saying your `panel` is in one page which is visible and your link is in some other page which is not visible then its not at all possible to achieve this.

Comment: Can you visualize the problem I mean with some image or any other way. I'll try to give any other possible solution if you wish!!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have Index.aspx page which has a list of product(Titles Only) and I have a separate product.aspx page which has accordion for each of those product information. On pageload of product.aspx (by default)  all accordions are collapsed/closed,respective panels opens and closes by clicking panel headings as expected ,but  now I want to open for eg. product 2 panel only if product2 title is clicked on ined.aspx. Hope that's clear explanation of what exactly I am looking for,thanks

Comment: Yea bit cleared now!! So how you are redirecting? through javascript of backend `.cs` page

Comment: Nothing in the background , simply (eg.) href = "page1.aspx"

Comment: So while doing `href="page1.aspx"` store the value in `localStorage` and then get it on `page2.aspx` and based on that show the required panel!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to Guruprasad Rao's comment, when you know which panel needs to be opened (pass data between pages), you can add 'in' class to the panel that needs to be opened by default. If you want, you can also activate accordions using javascript using the $('ID of your panel').collapse('show') function. See http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion

Comment: Thanks for reply.Yes, tried all these solutions but no luck, The only way it had worked was by adding an id of specific panel  to the current request url but obviously that url doesn't exists. To achieve this I need to find out the way to ignore that extra added id in url request  until specific page life-cycle  event. Once I get the requested page successfully then I should be able to check if that url has any (hidden) id with it and open that matching panel.